# Split at last occurrence of character then join

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, regex

I would like to split an `attribute` at the last occurrence of a character, then add a string and join the array back together. Here is a simplified **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldjoqtk1/1/)**.

In the demo I would like to split the `src` attribute at the last occurrence of the `.` and then add `-fx` to the `src` path.

**original `src` attributes**

`src="extension.jpg"`
`src="ext.ension.jpg"`

**what I am hoping to get**

`src="extension-fx.jpg"`
`src="ext.ension-fx.jpg"`

To be more specific, the issue is that if I `split('.')` and the path has multiple `.` problems arise (`-fx` not added properly).

```js
$('img').each(function(){
 var a = $(this).attr('src');
    var b = a.split('.')
    var c = b[0] + '-fx' + '.' + b[1];
    console.log(c);
    $(this).attr('src', c);    
});
```

```css
img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
}

img[src*="-fx.jpg"] {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="extension.jpg">
<img src="ext.ension.jpg">
```

Comment: Can you add an example of input string and expected output

Comment: @Tushar in the demo there is an example of it but I will also added it here to the post

Comment: Why not just split by `.jpg` then add it back with `-fx`?

Comment: @l'L'l Because, the extension of the image can be `.png` or `.gif` or `.jpeg`.

Comment: @Tushar: Even so a simple regex could handle that... `lastIndexOf` might be a better solution though.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use [`.attr( attributeName, function )`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) with callback function to update the attribute value of respective element. To add the string `-fx` in the src attribute, [`String#lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) and [`String#substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) can be used.

```js
// Get the src attribute value of image one by one
$('img').attr('src', function(i, src) {
  // Get the index of the last .
  var lastIndex = src.lastIndexOf('.');

  // Add the string before the last .
  // Return updated string, this will update the src attribute value
  return src.substr(0, lastIndex) + '-fx' + src.substr(lastIndex);
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
img[src$="-fx.jpg"] {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="extension.jpg" />
<img src="ext.ension.jpg" />
```

**Note:** The selector used `img[src*="-fx.jpg"]` will select all the images whose `src` attribute value contains the given string anywhere. To select images whose `src` value ends with given string, use `$=` selector.

```
img[src$="-fx.jpg"]
       ^
```

---

If you want to use regex, following regex can be used.

```
(\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif))$/
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/cC8nI7/2)

```js
// Get the src attribute value of image one by one
$('img').attr('src', function(i, src) {
  return src.replace(/(\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif))$/, "-fx$1");
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
img[src$="-fx.jpg"] {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="extension.jpg" />
<img src="ext.ension.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 15):

This is how you can do it by using `lastIndexOf` and 'substring' functions in javascript. I have just updated your fiddle. take a look at it

`lastIndexOf` -> will get the position of the character `.` and then using substring function you can join to get your desired result

```
$('img').each(function(){
    var a = $(this).attr('src');
    var pos = a.lastIndexOf('.');
    var newchar = a.substring(0,pos)+'-fx';
    var replacingchar = newchar+a.substr(pos);
    console.log(replacingchar);

});
```

**[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldjoqtk1/2/)**

Answer (score 8):

You can split at the last occurrence of . with:

```
split = str.match(/(.*)\.(.*)/)
```

If there is in fact at least one `.` (indicated in the RegExp as `\.`), the result will be an array of which element 2 is everything before the last `.` and element 3 is everything after it.

Answer (score 1):

You Can try like

```
var k="ext.abc.jpg";
var l= k.substring(0, k.lastIndexOf("."))+"-fx"+k.substring(k.lastIndexOf(".") , k.length);;
console.log(l);
```

Here i am dividing string into two parts first is a portion which is before .jpg and then adding "-fx" into that then adding last part including ".";