# Regex to find first opening and last closing bracket to split in JS

Tags: javascript, regex, split

tl;dr: I want to separate a string in JavaScript at the first opening and last closing bracket:

```
"abc(def)ghi"                ==>    ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
"abc(def(ghi)jkl)mno"        ==>    ["abc", "def(ghi)jkl", "mno"]
"abc(def(ghi(jkl)mno)pqr"    ==>    ["abc", "def(ghi(jkl)mno", "pqr"]
"abc(def(ghi)jkl)mno)pqr"    ==>    ["abc", "def(ghi)jkl)mno", "pqr"]
```

I tried to achieve this using

```
"abc(def(ghi)jkl)mno".split(new RegExp('\\\(|\\\)'))
```

but that seemsto match every bracket and gives me `["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno"]`.
I also tried this:

```
"abc(def(ghi)jkl)mno".split(new RegExp('\\\((?:.*)\\\)'))
```

but that seems to match the whole part inside the brackets as well and gives me `["abc", "mno"]`.

Is there a way to only separate at the first opening and the last closing bracket?

Comment: A non-regex solution might be faster and more elegant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34648186/split-at-last-occurrence-of-character-then-join

Comment: a non-regex solution, as mentioned by @ThomasMoors: `var i = str.indexOf('('), j = str.lastIndexOf(')', i+1), arr = !== -1 && j > i[str.substr(0,i), str.substr(i+1, j), str.substr(j+1)]: [str];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript seems to include matches from the Regex used in the split function in the resulting array. This is the code that worked for me:

```
"abc(def(ghi)jkl)mno".split(new RegExp('\\((.*)\\)'))
```

It gives me: `["abc", "def(ghi)jkl", "mno"]`

It captures everything that's between an opening and a closing bracket. Regex seems to have the middle part be greedy.

(I stumbled upon this by trying around while writing the question)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```js
var a1="abc(def)ghi";
var a2="abc(def(ghi)jkl)mno";
var a3="abc(def(ghi(jkl)mno)pqr";
var a4="abc(def(ghi)jkl)mno)pqr";

a1 = a1.split(new RegExp('\\((.*)\\)'));
a2 = a2.split(new RegExp('\\((.*)\\)'));
a3 = a3.split(new RegExp('\\((.*)\\)'));
a4 = a4.split(new RegExp('\\((.*)\\)'));

console.log(a1);
console.log(a2);
console.log(a3);
console.log(a4);
```